# Boolean expression from a State machine diagram

Tags: boolean-expression, karnaugh-map, state-diagram

I'm having trouble to determine the boolean equation for Q1 and Q2. What I did was to input the values into a karnaugh-map. But since the state Diagram only consists of 3 states (00, 01 and 11), I'm a bit unsure of how to setup the Karnaugh. I know what it would have looked like if it had four states like (00, 01, 11 and 10).

[image: State Diagram]

This is what my karnaugh looks like, it's probably wrong though

[image: This is what my karnaugh looks like, it's probably wrong though]

Edit: Should I add the last row (10) in my Karnaugh and just input don't care?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that the K-map is ok as a draft, but I would suggest making each of the output variables (the "new" `Q_1` and `Q_0` in the next step of the state diagram) their own K-map.

That way you can minimize the function separately for each of them.

I have filled the truth table this way:

```
+-----------------++-----------+
  input variables || next state
+-----+-----+-----++-----+-----+
| Q_1 | Q_0 |  x  || Y_1 | Y_0 |
+-----+-----+-----++-----+-----+
|  0  |  0  |  0  ||  0  |  1  |
|  0  |  0  |  1  ||  0  |  0  |
|  0  |  1  |  0  ||  0  |  0  |
|  0  |  1  |  1  ||  1  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----++-----+-----+
|  1  |  0  |  0  ||  X  |  X  |
|  1  |  0  |  1  ||  X  |  X  |
|  1  |  1  |  0  ||  0  |  0  |
|  1  |  1  |  1  ||  1  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----++-----+-----+
```

And the output functions determining the next state (`Y_1` as the "new" next `Q_1`, `Y_0` as the "new" next `Q_0`) are:

[image: Output functions in K-maps]

The indexes in the Karnaugh maps correspond with the rows of the truth table because of the order of the variables.

Also take notice, that I used the 'dont-care' X output (for `10` state) to advantage in minimization of the second function (`Q_0`).

The machine should (theoretically) never go to the 'dont-care' state, therefore you should not worry about using it in the function.

Without circling the `X` the `Y_0` function would be longer: `Y_0 = ¬x·¬Q_1·¬Q_0 + x·Q_0`. With the `X` it is only: `Y_0 = ¬x·¬Q_0 + x·Q_0`.

If it seem unclear to you, do not hesitate to ask in a comment, please.